# How to use Direlect3 with Mono-D

Tags: opengl, monodevelop, d

I was wondering if in Mono-D I could use Direlect3, I have everything downloaded here: https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3/blob/master/README.markdown but I can not find out how to use it in combination with Mono-D.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, Derelict3 is just a framework (a library, to simplify). If it is in your project's search path (-I flag to the compiler) then Mono-D will give you code completion. Sure you must configure your Mono-D project yourself. It is the same what you would do if you wrote the Makefile yourself (more/less). Should really be straightforward.